Is the set of software and hardware of modern attitude control systems exhaustive?
In the book ADCS - Spacecraft Attitude Determination and Control on page 426 there is a diagram of the JWST ACS. Next I attach a reproduction of it from the book.

The diagram shows the main soft- and hardware blocks of this system. It includes RCS thrusters, reaction wheels, IMU and FGS, star camera, torque control and distribution regulators, position control regulators, auxiliary astronomical blocks, etc.
It has been suggested that the Gaia has the best characteristics. The corresponding article also provides a high-level block diagram, which essentially presents the same set of main components.

There are some differences in the AСS for CubeSats. The used filters and types of controllers (Kalman and PID-) are described in more detail; there is also an additional block “magnetic field model” (Earth? Apparatus?) and a magnetometer. But otherwise it is the same control system as other spacecrafts.

In some cases, ACS has to be built with advanced controllers on board, but a limited set of sensors. Or vice versa, an expanded range of sensors, but simpler regulators. Thus, ACS deteriorates its capabilities in the case of severe restrictions on the soft- and hardware parts (provided that the general structure is preserved).
My question is: is this set of soft- and hardware position control systems generally comprehensive from a qualitative point of view (assuming there are no restrictions) and such systems do not need further improvement?

Assuming I am understanding your question correctly: No, there is still improvement to be made both in attitude control and attitude knowledge beyond what current hardware and software suites may offer even when fully unbounded.
For example, in Payload Space's recent piece on future very large telescopes enabled by larger launch vehicles with larger fairings, Charlie Atkinson, JWST chief engineer at Northrop Grumman, stated that while "James Webb is stable to tens of nanometers", for the Habitable Worlds Observatory, "we need to get Habitable Worlds’ stability to tens of picometers level".
This is a stability improvement of three orders of magnitude. Such advancements may necessitate new kinds of ADCS devices entirely.

You understood my question correctly.   The new demands on precision are amazing.  Why are such precise systems needed?

@ayr That would be its own question to ask. But a space telescope is dealing with more challenges than if you setup a telescope on a merry-go-round. Astronomy done by science is long-exposure photography. Movement and long-exposures don't mix well.

@DavidS Sometime later, perhaps. There is no need now.

Sometimes, control moment gyroscopes are employed instead of reaction wheels.
Gravity gradient and light pressure can be used.
In addition to unloading reaction wheels, magnetic torquers may be used directly to provide torque to change/control attitude.
Nutation dampers eliminate the wobble due to misalignment of the angular momentum axis with the spin axis.
NICER uses a gimbal to control its attitude, torquing against the inertia of the International Space Station. It uses tuned mass dampers to reduce disturbances from the irregular motion of the station.

It is worth noting that magnetorquers only really work when you're in the presence of a strong magnetic field like Earth's. This is why deep space probes like Voyager-1 use other methods like reaction control thrusters for attitude control.

Let's take a look at the attitude dynamics equations. $$ \begin{cases}
\dot{\Omega}_1 = \frac{1}{J_1} (J_2-J_3)\Omega_2\Omega_3 + u_1\
\dot{\Omega}_2 = \frac{1}{J_2} (J_3-J_1)\Omega_1\Omega_3 + u_2\
\dot{\Omega}_3 = \frac{1}{J_3} (J_1-J_2)\Omega_1\Omega_2 + u_3
\end{cases} $$  and $\Omega_1 = \dot{\phi},\Omega_2 = \dot{\theta},\Omega_3 = \dot{\psi}$ where $\phi,\theta,\psi$ - attitude rotation angles and $u_1,u_2,u_3$ - control torques.
Force-torque devices are the source of those same control moments? Does each control moment require its own device?

@ayr A CMG with two gimbals can control two axes.

@JohnDoty is correct. Three gimbals on a CMG would give 3-axis control. Then you have reaction wheels, where there are many arrangements but a common one is with a wheel oriented in each axis, giving one axis of control from each wheel, and usually another wheel canted from the others as a backup. There is also the 4-wheel pyramid arrangement which together also grants 3-axis control that is tolerant of a wheel going out.

@MichaelBonnet A CMG works by adjusting the direction of its angular momentum axis in the body frame. That's a two parameter problem. The third degree of freedom is the magnitude of its angular momentum. You can't adjust that with a gimbal: you need to change the wheel speed. It essentially behaves as a reaction wheel, not a CMG, about its axis. The limitations of a reaction wheel apply.

@JohnDoty I thought that a force-torque device is a drive corresponding to an axis, which only controls it.

@ayr A torque device with one control input will, instantaneously, torque about one axis. But that axis may not be fixed in either the body or inertial space (consider a magtorquer). A two gimbal CMG has two inputs, so it's more complicated.

@JohnDoty http://www.ecpsystems.com/docs/ECP_Gyroscope_Model_750.pdf you are talking about such devices, for example, right?

@MichaelBonnet https://ibb.co/Vp2ysM0 you mean such devices, right?

@ayr Yes. Note that the triple gimbal doesn't give you a third control axis, but it allows you to avoid "gimbal lock", where two axis control degenerates into one axis.
